# Google sheets dynamically build an array from another

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Say I have:

[image]

But on a separate worksheet I would like to generate a new table of the following data of totals:

[image]

I am stumped as to how to have this using as few formulas as possible - I don't want to copy paste the same formula among the rows, because my data could be any number of rows long

Additionally, what if there was another column called "timestamp" (of the action), would we be able t do things like generating a table of data that is only within a range of dates?

Does anyone have the secret sauce?

I have gotten close, where I can use ARRAYFORMULA to extend the calculation for one column for every row, but I can't figure out how to have this formula work for every column.

A prepared spreadsheet and my attempt is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cbLafPF-ajNSVMid8MCBNDSWstvDuMJe89Q1eAtvW4Q/edit?usp=sharing

I encourage you to have an attempt (the cells with the formulas in 'my attempt' I have colored orange)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a `MAP`, `QUERY` pivot combination that you can use

```
=MAP(QUERY(A131:B149,"Select B,count(B) where A<>'' 
                      group by B pivot A",1), 
       LAMBDA(toZero, IF(toZero="", 0, toZero)))
```

*(**Do** adjust the formula according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

Comment: :) I got it close with this: `=QUERY({data!A2:A,data!B2:B},"select Col2,count(Col2) group by Col2 pivot Col1",0)`

Feel free to have a look at the linked sheet

Comment: I'm not sure why your range has 131 and 149 in it?

Comment: This is perfect: `=QUERY({data!A2:A,data!B2:B},"Select Col2,count(Col2) where Col1!='' group by Col2 pivot Col1")`

Comment: *"I'm not sure why your range has 131 and 149 in it"*.  **Do** adjust the formula according to your ranges and locale.